# pubg crashes whole system to the point of forced shutdown

Tags: technical-issues, pubg-battlegrounds

I could play the game for years without this problem occuring. This error started about 1 week ago.

### **The Problem**

As far as I can tell this seems not reproducable. It happens during the game as well as in the menu. Once it definitely happened when I clicked on quit (or exit?) game in the main menu. The screen turns black, all audio cuts out, sometimes I can hear a little noise and this drags down the entire operating system. No ALT+F4, ALT+Tab, CTRL+ALT+DELETE is working. I have to manually press the power key on my computer for 5 seconds to forcefully shut it off.

### **The Setup**

> CPU Intel Core i7 6700K 4x 4.00GHz So.1151 WOF
>   MB ASRock Z170 Extreme3 Intel Z170 So.1151 Dual Channel DDR ATX Retail
>   SSD   250GB Samsung 850 Evo 2.5" (6.4cm) SATA 6Gb/s TLC Toggle (MZ-75E250B/EU)
>   VGA 8192MB Sapphire Radeon R9 390 Nitro inkl. Backplate Aktiv PCIe 3.0 x16 1xDVI / 1xHDMI / 3xDisplayPort (Lite Retail)
>   DDR4  16GB (2x 8192MB) G.Skill RipJaws V DDR4-3200 DIMM CL16-18-18-38 Dual Kit
>   HDSA  2000GB Seagate Surveillance HDD ST2000VX000 7.200U/min 64MB 3.5" (8.9cm) SATA 6Gb/s
>    PSU  650 Watt Corsair RMx Series Modular 80+ Gold
>   NET Gigabyte WB867D-I WLAN + Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter PCIe 802.11ac PCIe x1
>   Win7 Home Premium 64bit / Win10 Professional 64bit

No other software is running at the same time except for discord and or teamspeak.

### **What I tried so far**

I upgraded from Win7 to Win10, completely formatted the SSD and made a clean install. Installed steam and pubg freshly on the ssd. Made sure all the drivers are up to date. There's no error message or other notification when I reboot, so I can not even tell what went wrong.